# Replacing NULL Value in huge df causing error: python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dataframe, isnull

I have 2 set of dfs which are very huge in rowcount about to 39k and column count about to 400k and with below command I am trying to replace 2 dataframe NULL values. Since this df's are dynamic so I cant specify fillna in specific column I want to replace full df NULL to NA.

```
str_cols = df1.columns[df1.dtypes==object] 
df1[str_cols] = df1[str_cols].fillna('.',inplace=True) 
df1 = df1[pd.isnull(df1).any(1)].fillna('NA')

str_cols_1 = df2.columns[df2.dtypes==object] 
df2[str_cols_1] = df2[str_cols_1].fillna('.',inplace=True) 
df2=df2[pd.isnull(df1).any(1)].fillna('NA')
```

I get this error message:

> C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4244:
> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
**kwargs
Traceback (most recent call last):

File line 1, in 
runfile('C:/Users///Desktop/Pythonscript/s2.py.py', wdir='C:/Users//Desktop/Pythonscript')

```
"C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/<user>/<path>/Desktop/Pythonscript/s2.py.py", line 29, in df1=df1[pd.isnull(df1).any(1)].fillna('NA')

File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4244, in fillna **kwargs

File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 6279, in fillna value=value, limit=limit, inplace=inplace, downcast=downcast

File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 575, in fillna return self.apply("fillna", **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 438, in apply applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 441, in fillna return self.split_and_operate(mask, f, inplace)

File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 493, in split_and_operate nv = f(m, v, i)

File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 434, in f block = self.coerce_to_target_dtype(value)

File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 1079, in coerce_to_target_dtype return self.astype(object)

 File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 559, in astype
    return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors, values=values, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 639, in _astype
    values = self.get_values(dtype=dtype)
```

Comment: There is something missing from your error traceback, please double-check. It should start with a line that looks like `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and end with a line that looks like `SomeKindOfError: description of what went wrong`.

Comment: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4244: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  **kwargs
Traceback (most recent call last):

File line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/<user>/<path>/Desktop/Pythonscript/s2.py.py', wdir='C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/Pythonscript')

Comment: Please fix it in the OP by using the `edit` button. Adding a comment is not helpful.

Comment: Done .This fillna command is even taking too long to replace NULL values.How to use it effectively that it can run faster.

Answer (score 0):

> If you wish to replace the entire dataframe values having NULL with an NA you can use the following.

```
df.fillna('NA', inplace=True)
```

> If you wish to replace the column values of type object having NULL with an NA you can use the following.

```
cols = df.columns[df.dtypes==object]

for i in cols:
   df[i] = df[i].fillna('NA', inplace=True)
```